# onclick and <a> not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, css, hyperlink, onclick

Here is my code:

```
<div style="position:absolute;z-index: -1; right: 0; top: 0; width: 30%; height: 100%;">
    <a href="&next"><img id="next" src="img/next.png" style="height:100%;width:100%"></a>
</div>
```

The `a` doesn't work well, it just works on the top left of the image. this is quite a big problem for me as this is part of a faq page where you can scroll trough questions with < and > at the sides on the page.

I'm having the same problem with the previous one (at the left). I tried doing `position:relative` and `float:right` and it only worked on the bottom half of the image.

Can anyone help?

Comment: can you please provide fiddle link

Comment: sure... wait a sec

Comment: provide a fiddle or code snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply put z-index:1 like this

```
<div style="position:absolute;z-index: 1; right: 0; top: 0; width: 30%; height: 100%;">
    <a href="&next"><img id="next" src="next.png" style="height:100%;width:100%"></a>
</div>
```

I think it may work

Comment: im using it on http://smtcs.pe.hu / but the problem is it only works on the top left

Comment: wow thanks i may need to test it myself, afterwards ill give you correct awnser thing

Comment: ok, onclick doesnt work but the code works fine so i can use that to do the stuff. thanks so much i'm stuck on this from days. :)

Answer (score 1):

By default `<a>` has inline style, try:

```
 <a style="display: block;"></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally when you want to develop some next/previous kind of layouts on HTML, it should be like this:

**Container:**

For the container, you should make it absolute and cover full area of the document. For achieving the same create an html structure and use css classes.

**Next/Prev:**

For the navigation buttons, you just need to define the width and opacity of the same. And after making sure of the arrow images are vertically centered you need to write then into container scope.

Below are the code samples for these 2 components:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <a href="&next" class="next">
      <span class="helper"></span><img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" height=25 />
    </a>
    <a href="&prev" class="prev">
       <span class="helper"></span><img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" height=25 />
    </a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container{
    position:absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: grey;
 }

.next{
    position:absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 50px;
    height: 100%;
    background: lightblue;
 }
.prev{
    position:absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 50px;
    height: 100%;
    background: lightgreen;
 }
.helper {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.next img, .prev img{
    background: #3A6F9A;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
```

A Full example can be found here: [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/krunal2450/ynpq6g72/1/)

Comment: yes, next time ill need css ill follow this. thanks anyway also if i was already awnsered.

Comment: i upvoted you but it wont show up until i have 15 exp